# how to update the values of a dataFrame column in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm having a data frame that contains abbreviation of countries name:

```
+--+----+
|Id|Code|
+--+----+
|1 |FR  |
|2 |FR  |
|3 |FR  |
|4 |Es  |
|5 |Es  |
|6 |Es  |
|7 |IT  |
+--+----+
```

also I have an enum contains the the name of countries and its abbreviation  :

```
object Countries extends Enumeration {
    type Countries=Mapping
    case class Mapping(abr:String,value:String) extends Val
    val FR=Mapping("FR","France")
    val ES=Mapping("ES","Spain")
    val IT=Mapping("IT","ITALY")
}
```

so I want to map each abbreviation with the appropriate name, I know that I could use, the *when* function, but I wonder if there is a better way, like a map function (that map each string with an other one)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way in my opinion is to create a dataframe for the map, and then do a join between the 2 tables.

Comment: yeah its a great idea

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scala Map of the mappings like the following:

```
object Countries extends Enumeration {
    type Countries=Mapping
    case class Mapping(abr:String,value:String) extends Val
    val FR=Mapping("FR","France")
    val ES=Mapping("ES","Spain")
    val IT=Mapping("IT","ITALY")
    val map: Map[String, String] = List(FR, ES, IT).map(mapping => (mapping.abr -> mapping.value)).toMap
  }
```

Now the `map` contains the required mappings.
Next thing to do is to iterate over the dataframe and we can use the map we created to get the country name using the country code:

```
object Application extends App {
  //create spark session and dataframe here

  val countryMapping = Countries.map
  val dataSet = df.as[(String, String)] //convert to dataSet for iteration with type safety
  val resultDS = dataSet.map{ case (id, code) => (id, countryMapping.get(code))}
  val resultDF = resultDS.toDF("Id", "Country") //convert back to dataframe

  resultDF.show
}
```